# How do you say "a voracious learner with 5X ABC certification"/"a voracious learner with 5X ABC certificates" on resume?

Tags: word-choice

I am just confused how to write the below sentence ?

> a voracious learner with 5X Microsoft Azure *certifications*

OR

> a voracious learner with 5X Microsoft Azure *certificates*.

I have to mention "Azure" in order to be very specific about the knowledge I have about the type of cloud.

Comment: For those of us much less qualified, does that mean that you have 5 certificates of X rating or several certificates of 5X rating? What are 5X certificates?

Comment: Including an element like **5X** (presumably meaning *five of, five times*) in the text marks it out as "technobabble" anyway, so it's not really worth thinking about "grammatical correctness" in this context. Both nouns (*certification* and *certificate*) are perfectly "valid" in the cited context, but the former is very much less likely (we don't normally use *certification* as a "countable" noun like that).

Comment: Thanks a lot @FumbleFingers for your answer.

Comment: @RonaldSole, as FumbleFingers said that 5X is nothing but shows the number of certificates I have. 
-- For those of us much less qualified
-- Even I am not that qualified to use such impressive things in my sentences, credit goes to LinkedIn's much trending headlines : ) !

Comment: If this was a resume that I was reviewing, I'd have stopped at "voracious"

Comment: Yes, I'd go with **certificates**. As to **voracious**, I think it would depend on who I was trying to impress.

Comment: @JamesK, Thanks for your answer. I'd have stopped at "voracious" -- I got a bit confused, U would have stopped at voracious because either the word is not famous enough to impress recruiters or it is awesomely attractive. Which one is applicable for you ? Though I think it's not that common but can impress people with it's usage. Please do let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The problem with ***voracious*** here is it's a very evocative/emotive term, more typically used in fiction and "sensationalist" writing. That's not what people expect in a CV, where a "toned down" alternative such as ***keen*** would probably work better.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FumbleFingers for pointing that out to me. I will surely make the necessary changes.